# How to set auto-scaling on an app (optimized for iPhone 6's 4.7 inch screen) to fit iPhone 5 and 4's screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have seen old iOS apps auto-scale to fit iPhone 6/6+'s large screen on iOS 8. I have recently developed an app which is optimized to display on iPhone 6's 4.7 inch screen. Apply auto-layouts would be lots of work because a lot of views are created programmatically so I am wondering is it possible to make an app auto-scale to fit smaller screens?

Comment: If you want to do programmatically means, you need to relate all the views together with their frames. You need to set the e.g uilabel width as related to general screen width([uiscreen mainscreen]bounds].size.width) . Otherwise you need to use sizeclasses throught xib.

Comment: Auto-layout *is* how you make an app adapt to the different screen sizes.  You can set constraints programatically if you don't want to use Interface Builder

Comment: @Paulw11 Is using auto-layout the only way? For my app it's a lot easier to create another xib than applying auto-layout to the current xib.

Comment: Auto layout is how you "auto scale" as per your question.  You can write some/lots of special case code to handle the different size screens and when Apple releases the iPhone 7 with a 32" screen you have to go and do it again... There is no simple "use this xib file on iPhone 4, use this on iPhone5..." setting

Answer (score 0):

1. Use auto layout in code
2. Refactor your code to support different screen sizes
3. Refactor your code to size views as percentage of screen size